# encoding/factoring lists in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, encoding, one-hot-encoding

I am attempting to encode lists of categories within a dataframe by factoring them.  I will then be creating a matrix from this series of lists (normalizing them to a set length, creating a multidimensional array, and one-hot encoding the elements in the matrix).

However, the factors do not maintain consistency between the rows.
This can be seen here:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [ ['Other', 'Male', 'Female', 'Male', 'Other'], ['Female', 'Other', 'Male'] ]})
>>> df['B'] = df.A.apply(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0])
>>> df
                                    A                B
0  [Other, Male, Female, Male, Other]  [0, 1, 2, 1, 0]
1               [Female, Other, Male]        [0, 1, 2]
```

Does anyone know how to maintain an encoding for this series that is the same among rows?

Comment: does get_dummies not work for your use case?

Comment: Thank you for the `get_dummies` idea, I really like the way that create one-hot vectors.  Unfortunately, I haven;t yet figured out a way to remove all of the one-hot vectors from the series back into a 3D tensor type of shape, when the lists of each element are not of equal length.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`LabelEncoder`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) from sklearn:

Fit the encoder:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit([s for l in df.A for s in l])
```

Transform the column:

```
df.A.apply(le.transform)
#0    [2, 1, 0, 1, 2]
#1          [0, 2, 1]
#Name: A, dtype: object

le.classes_
#array(['Female', 'Male', 'Other'], 
#      dtype='<U6')
```

Comment: Thanks, I really like this for the ease of which you can get back to the labels with `df['C']=df.B.apply(lambda x: le.classes_[x])`.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily do it yourself using all of the values in column `A`.

First, use a set comprehension to create a collection of all unique items in column `A`.  Then use a dictionary comprehension where the keys are these unique items and the values are enumerated based on these sorted unique items.

Then lookup the items in this dictionary using a list comprehension.

```
s = set(item for sublist in df.A for item in sublist)
s = {k: n for n, k in enumerate(sorted(list(s)))}

>>> df.assign(B=[[s[key] for key in sublist] for sublist in df['A']])
                                    A                B
0  [Other, Male, Female, Male, Other]  [2, 1, 0, 1, 2]
1               [Female, Other, Male]        [0, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a good answer since you have a lot of control over the encoding.  I made my own Encoder class for doing one-hot encoding, Huffman encoding, and index encodings, but I also wanted to see other ideas for maintaining consistency and not having tons of code cluttering up things just to define encodings